# Retrieve headers HTTP data from client Go Language

Tags: api, go

How to retrieve headers data value from client **API** using Go language?

I'm using beego framework (beego.me)

and here is sample result to retrieve data from body

```
func (u *UserController) Post() {
    var user models.User
    json.Unmarshal(u.Ctx.Input.RequestBody, &user)
    uid := models.AddUser(user)
    u.Data["json"] = map[string]string{"uid": uid}
    u.ServeJSON()
}
```

Comment: please provide more specifics of what you are trying to do - code example etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego/context#BeegoInput.Header), you can do this:

```
log.Println(u.Ctx.Input.Header("X-My-Header"))
```

All headers at once can be obtained from an `*http.Request`:

```
log.Println(u.Ctx.Request.Header)
```